# Query not correct?

Tags: mysql

Can anyone see an obvious error in this query?

```
function getFixtureDetails($league, $date, $status)
{
    global $database;
    $q = "SELECT g.id, g.home_user, g.home_user2, g.away_user, g.away_user2, g.home_score, g.away_score, hteam.team AS hometeam, ateam,team AS awayteam, 
          huser.username AS home_username, huser2.username AS home_username2, auser.username AS away_username, auser2.username AS away_username2
          FROM ".TBL_FOOT_GAMES." g
          INNER JOIN ".TBL_FOOT_TEAMS." hteam ON hteam.id = g.home_team
          INNER JOIN ".TBL_FOOT_TEAMS." ateam ON ateam.id = g.away_team
          INNER JOIN ".TBL_USERS." huser ON huser.id = g.home_user
          LEFT JOIN ".TBL_USERS." huser2 ON huser2.id = g.home_user2
          INNER JOIN ".TBL_USERS." auser ON auser.id = g.away_user
          LEFT JOIN ".TBL_USERS." auser2 ON auser2.id = g.away_user2
          WHERE g.fixture_date = '$date' AND g.leagueid = '$league' AND (g.type = '2' OR g.type = '12' OR g.type = '22' OR g.type = '32') AND g.status = '$status'
          ORDER BY g.fixture_date";
    return mysql_query($q, $database->myConnection());
}
```

Thanks

Edit, error message...

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: Why not include the error message you're getting?

Comment: The error message you added is not the right one; the output of `mysql_error()` would be interesting.

Comment: Tried that, doesnt work.

Comment: Error: You are not using prepared statements.

Comment: @Luke are you saying `echo mysql_error()` doesn't return anything? That is *very* unlikely.

Comment: Used mysql_error and found it. ypercube has found it too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ateam.team AS awayteam,
```

not

```
ateam,team AS awayteam,
```

Comment: I got here 5 minutes late, saw no-one had got the answer, and decided to read the query from bottom up hoping to be first if the error was near the end. Dang! +1